# Superimpose two imagesc with two dfferent handles so that it can be individually set the 'CData' later

Tags: matlab

I have to imagesc handle that needs to be overlapped, and it needs to be able to do `set(h1, 'CData' data)` later for performance issue inside a loop. However, this requirement make it hard to overlap with each other.

```
data1 = rand(100, 100);
data1 = rand(100, 100);

figure;
h1 = imagesc(data1);
colormap('hot')
h1.AlphaData = 0.5;

figure;
h2 = imagesc(data2);
colormap('cool')
h2.AlphaData = 0.5;

for 1=1:200
    data1 = rand(100, 100);
    set(h1, 'CData', data1);
    data2 = rand(100, 100);
    set(h2, 'CData', data2);

    % How do I overlap these two images here? If possible the most efficient way possible since the data will be a large matrix in real-life.

    drawnow;
end
```

Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

*Edit: Expected output would be something similar to this, where the two images superimposed with each other at half transparency (or without reducing the the transparency is also fine, as long as both maps/images easily distinguishable in the superimposed image):*

[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

[image: Superimposed]

([taken from mathworks forum](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/476715-superimposing-two-imagesc-graphs-over-each-other))

The linked reference is creating a new image object every time if it were to put inside a loop, I was trying to avoid that. That's why I resolved to `CData` approach.

Comment: What do you mean with “overlapped”? Do you want to show one image as a semi-transparent layer on top of the other? Please be specific with your description, and show an example of your aimed output if possible.

Comment: Sorry, I should be more clear. Yep that's what I meant. Do see the edited post.

Comment: So you already have code to overlap two images. That code saves the handles to the images, you can update the CData there too. Not sure what is missing?

Comment: I believe the key was to use `hold all` before create `h2`. However, doing that makes the whole figure takes the 'cool' colormap, which essentially makes data1 indistinguishable from data2, making it looks like it's a part of h2. I was trying to use `colormap(ax1, 'hot')` and `colormap(ax2, 'cool')`, however I was still having the same issue where they're not distinguishable.

Comment: Okay I think it's because of the colormap that I use. Seems like choosing the right color map works "okay". I wonder if there's any good alternative by normalizing (or any other method) `data1` and `data2`, so that it has no need to use two handles, but both can be normalized to be a single data, but can be displayed on a single image map clearly and in a distinct way. Do you have any idea or lead on this?

Comment: The most trivial thing you can do with your two grayscale images is compose them into an RGB image by assigning green to one image and red + blue to the other: `cat(3,data2,data1,data2)`.

Comment: That's really good idea! Thanks for the suggestion!